# Obtener ViewGroup en onCreate desde un Fragment

Tags: java, android

El problema es el siguiente: Necesito obtener el ViewGroup para inflar y así poder inicializar mi RecyclerView porqué cuando cambio de Tab (Pestaña) y regreso a esta tengo todo el Fragment en blanco. He estado leyendo y probando y dicen que lo debo de hacer en onCreate, no lo consigo, otros que en onAttach, dónde?

Dejo un fragmento del código...

```
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // AQUÍ QUIERO INFLAR Y HACER LO DE onCreateView
}

...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_list, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_news_list);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    updateUI();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
}

protected void updateUI() {
    List<News> news = NewsLab.getInstance(getActivity()).getArticles();

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(news));
    } else {
        mAdapter.setNews(news);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

...
```

Actualizo

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

// PROPERTIES

private ViewPager mViewPager;

// MENU METHODS

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.to_search_menu_item:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

// METHODS

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    setupViewPager(mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container));

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new NewsTagFragment(), getString(R.string.tag_news));
    adapter.addFragment(new CommercesTagFragment(), getString(R.string.tag_commerces));
    adapter.addFragment(new OffersTagFragment(), getString(R.string.tag_offers));
    adapter.addFragment(new ServicesTagFragment(), getString(R.string.tag_services));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// INNED CLASSES

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // PROPERTIES

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    // CONSTRUCTORS

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // METHODS

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    // OVERRIDE METHODS

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Error en consola: /RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lo correcto es inflar tus vistas en `onCreateView()`.**

podrías usar `getView()` pero el problema es que es inicializado hasta que `onCreateView()` ha finalizado.

Me parece que tu problema en el cual regresas a tu tab y se ve blanco el fragment en realidad es por tu adapter.

Asegura de usar en tu Adapter: `getChildFragmentManager()`
por ejemplo:

```
 mAdapter = new miTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: No puedo acceder al método getChildFragmentManager desde mi Adaptador de Tabs. [Actualizo Pregunta con más datos]